# Are device files implemented by device drivers or OS kernels?

Tags: linux, files, devices

Device files are interfaces of device drivers to user programs.

In Linux, is a device file implemented directly by its corresponding device driver, or by the OS kernel (excluding the device driver)?

Comment: `udev` might also be worth reading up on.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel generates the device files, but functions such as `read` and `write` are mostly implemented by drivers that can be integrated in the kernel.

A good free (Creative Commons) book talks about it: [Linux Device Drivers](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)